# Using MIN and IF excel formula in python, but excel is adding @ symbol in the formula and the cell shows #value! error

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

This is how it is in Python code:

```py
for x in enumerate(rows):
    df[('country','state','zipcode')][x] = "=IF(AB{}<AC{},A$3)".format(x)
```

but in Excel the cell has `#VALUE!` and the formula is

```
"=@IF(@AB4<@AC4,A$3)".format(x)
```

How can I make it work? What can be done so that the formula does not add the `@` symbol?

Comment: The @ is the implicit intersection operator, introduced to support Dynamic Arrays.  Writing to the Formula property introduces that operator.   Formula2 was added to allow you to explicitly _not_ add the @ operator.   Does your Python library  support that?

Comment: Regarding `"=IF(AB{}<AC{},A$3)".format(x)`, you've got 2 sets of curly brackets but only 1 argument in the call to `format`. That should result in a `IndexError`, no?